# Check if a file exists?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

trying to check whether the file I want to read exists or not.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here are another approaches:

1. Using `BFILE` and `fileexists` function of `dbms_lob` package:

   ```
   create or replace function FileExists(
      p_DirName in varchar2,     -- schema object name
      p_FileName in varchar2
    ) return number
   is
     l_file_loc bfile;
   begin
     l_file_loc := bfilename(upper(p_DirName), p_FileName);
     return dbms_lob.fileexists(l_file_loc);  -- 1 exists; 0 - not exists
   end;
   ```
2. Using `fgetattr` function of `utl_file` package:

   ```
   create or replace function FileExists(
     p_DirName in varchar2,     -- schema object name
     p_FileName in varchar2
   ) return number
   is
     l_fexists boolean;
     l_flen   number;
     l_bsize  number;
     l_res    number(1);
   begin
     l_res := 0;
     utl_file.fgetattr(upper(p_DirName), p_FileName, l_fexists, l_flen, l_bsize);
     if l_fexists
     then
       l_res := 1;
     end if;  
     return l_res;
   end;
   ```

Comment: @ElShaikhaShaikha Try to grant `execute` privilege on `UTL_FILE` package to a user that going to use that package or to the `public`.

Comment: Thanks. I did not have to grant execute on UTL_FILE to public. The first function worked perfectly. I edited it to fit my DB needs. Thank you again for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Creating a function that checks if a file exists is fairly easy by just trying to open it and catching any exceptions (this example function taken from [AskTom](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:7682748147019))

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION file_exists(p_fname IN VARCHAR2) RETURN BOOLEAN
AS
  l_file UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE;
BEGIN
  l_file := UTL_FILE.FOPEN(SUBSTR( p_fname, 1, instr(p_fname,'/',-1) ),
                           SUBSTR( p_fname, instr( p_fname, '/', -1)+1 ), 'r' );   
  UTL_FILE.FCLOSE( l_file );
  RETURN TRUE;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN UTL_FILE.INVALID_PATH      THEN RETURN FALSE;
  WHEN UTL_FILE.INVALID_OPERATION THEN RETURN FALSE;
END;
/
```

Then you can just use;

```
IF ( file_exists( 'MED_LIST_19_OCT_12.csv' ) )
...
```

Comment: I get these errors: Error(7,1): PL/SQL: Statement ignored
Error(7,1): PLS-00201: identifier 'UTL_FILE' must be declared

Comment: @ElShaikhaShaikha To keep things secure (ie you don't want anyone with SQL access to read/write everywhere in your file system), you'll need to enable it explicitly in init.ora for the directories you're interested in, see for example [this link](http://utplsql.sourceforge.net/Doc/admin.html) how to do that.

Answer (score 2):

Use `UTL_FILE.FGETATTR` function.
This function is designed specifically for this purpose.

### Syntax:

```
UTL_FILE.FGETATTR(
   location     IN VARCHAR2, 
   filename     IN VARCHAR2, 
   fexists      OUT BOOLEAN, 
   file_length  OUT NUMBER, 
   block_size   OUT BINARY_INTEGER);
```

### Example:

```
DECLARE
  fexists      BOOLEAN;
  file_length  NUMBER;
  block_size   BINARY_INTEGER;
BEGIN

    UTL_FILE.FGETATTR('MY_ORA_DIRECTORY', 'my_file_name.csv', fexists, file_length, block_size);
    IF fexists THEN
       -- Do something
       -- ...
    END IF;

END IF;
```

Oracle documentation:
https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/u_file.htm#ARPLS70915

One more useful link:
https://www.foxinfotech.in/2018/09/how-to-check-if-file-exists-in-pl-sql.html

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. Would you mind adding an example of how you'd use `UTL_FILE.FGETATTR` within the answer itself, just in case the site you've linked to goes down? Also, if you haven't done so already, please [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read ["How do I write a good answer?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: Thank you, guys. I have corrected the answer. Hope, now, it looks better )