# PL/SQL: check if a varchar is an URL

Tags: url, plsql

Is there a way in PL/SQL to check if a varchar is a valid URL that opens a file?

For example, if I have as a varchar `https://toto.sharepoint.com/myFiles/file.pdf`

Is there a way to know whether the file `file.pdf` exists or not?

Comment: See this discussion: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13980871/check-if-a-file-exists

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no way that PL/SQL can tell if a given URL on the internet is valid.

You'll need to write some code in some client language that walks the database and performs an HTTP request across the internet for each URL.